# Laravel wizard system getting data from db

Tags: laravel

I am creating wizard systeem i create taks and wizard. but i want to show the take as stap not all the taks in one stap.

```
<div class="slide" id="slide-2" style="display: none">
     @foreach($tasks as $task)
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="task[{{ $loop->index }}]">{{ $task->name }</label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="task[]" id="task[{{ $loop->index }}]" value="{{ $task->id }}">
          </div>
     @endforeach 
</div>
```

But now I get all task in one time, how can I get one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$tasks` is an array and you can get array value one by one by key or index

for example:

`$tasks[0]->name` display first index of `$tasks` name or `$tasks[0]->id`

and `$tasks[1]->name` to get second  and ...

of course there are many ways to get values , it depends on how do you want to use it

`for` loop or `switch` or other loops with conditions

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, i did like you said but unfortunately doesn't work.     @foreach($tasks as $task)
         @if($task[0]->name)
             <input type="checkbox" name="task" id="task[{{ $loop->index[0] }}]" value="{{ $task->name }}">
           @endif@endforeach